# Use React Component in vanilla html/css/javascript project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'd like to use one React Native Component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-chat) inside my vanilla javascript project.

Is it possible to **render React Native component inside vanilla javascript** project? If so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating an iOS or Android app? I assume not because you are doing vanilla JS which can't be used alone for an app. In that case you can't use a React Native package. It is meant for iOS and Android, not HTML. Try looking for React packages.